# Customize gtkrc theme xfce-flat

Tags: 16.04, xfce, customization, gtkrc

I want to change color of the left sidebar

[image: ScreenShot]

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Thunar, you can change the side-pane's color by editing a file called **thunar.rc**. Its location depends on where your theme is. I like to have my themes in `~/.themes` and so my *thunar.rc* has this filepath: `/home/dkb/.themes/MyGreybird/gtk-2.0/apps/thunar.rc`.

In my *thunar.rc*, right at the top, I have:

```
style "sidepane"
{
    GtkTreeView::vertical-separator = 4

    base[NORMAL]        = @link_color
    base[INSENSITIVE]   = mix (0.4, shade (1.35,@selected_bg_color), shade (0.9,@base_color))

    text[NORMAL]        = mix (0.7, @text_color, @base_color)
    text[ACTIVE]        = mix (0.7, @text_color, @base_color)
    text[SELECTED]      = mix (0.7, @text_color, @base_color)
```

When I have

```
base[NORMAL]        = @link_color
```

Thunar's side-pane looks like this:

[image: Thunar side-pane blue]

When I have

```
base[NORMAL]        = mix (0.1, shade (1.35,@selected_bg_color), shade (0.9,@base_color))
```

Thunar's side-pane looks like this:

[image: Thunar's side pane grey]

*@link_color*, *@selected_bg_color*, and *@base_color* are defined in your theme's *gtkrc*. In my case, the filepath is this: `/home/dkb/.themes/MyGreybird/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`.

You can define your own color in *gtkrc* by just adding to the list of defined colors:

For example, you may have:

```
gtk-color-scheme    = "bg_color:#777777\nselected_bg_color:#398ee7\nbase_color:#666666" # Background, base.
gtk-color-scheme    = "fg_color:#3C3C3C\nselected_fg_color:#ffffff\ntext_color:#212121" # Foreground, text.
gtk-color-scheme    = "tooltip_bg_color:#000000\ntooltip_fg_color:#E1E1E1" # Tooltips.
gtk-color-scheme    = "link_color:#2d71b8" # Hyperlinks
gtk-color-scheme    = "panel_bg:#686868" # Panel bg color
gtk-color-scheme    = "fm_color:#F7F7F7" # Color used in Nautilus and Thunar.
gtk-color-scheme    = "bg_color_dark:#686868\ntext_color_dark:#FFF"
```

Then just add something like:

```
gtk-color-scheme    = "my_thunar_sidepane_color:#2c2c2c"
```

if you want to match the color of the main pane, for example. Save *gtkrc* and modify *thunar.rc* to use *your defined color* and reload your theme. When you next open Thunar, it should reflect the change you made.

Comment: i cannot find directory .themes on my `/home/username ` where is it ?

Comment: In that case, look in `/usr/share/themes`. You'll need sudo to make changes.